# Mongodb Aggregation Framework: Sum values for max date in month

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I receive data from a service on a weekly basis that I put into a collection. The data has an amount, projectNo and the dataDate timestamp. Using the aggregation framework I sum the amount and group by projectNo and dataDate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: {projectNo: 1, bdgtAppd: 1, dataDate: 1}},
    {$group: {_id: {
                projectNo: "$projectNo", 
                dataDate: "$dataDate"
                }, 
            amount: {$sum: "$bdgtAppd"}}
    },
    {$project: {_id:0, 
                projectNo:"$_id.projectNo", 
                dataDate:"$_id.dataDate", 
                amount:"$amount"
                }
    },
    {$sort: {projectNo:1,dataDate:1}}
])
```

Which yields this:

```
[{
    "amount" : 7887,
    "projectNo" : "5544A",
    "dataDate" : "2015-01-02T08:00:00.000Z"
}, {
    "amount" : 137947,
    "projectNo" : "5544A",
    "dataDate" : "2015-01-16T08:00:00.000Z"
}, {
    "amount" : 137947,
    "projectNo" : "5544A",
    "dataDate" : "2015-01-23T08:00:00.000Z"
}, {
    "amount" : 137947,
    "projectNo" : "5544A",
    "dataDate" : "2015-01-30T08:00:00.000Z"
}, {
    "amount" : 130060,
    "projectNo" : "5544A",
    "dataDate" : "2015-02-06T08:00:00.000Z"
}, {
    "amount" : 130060,
    "projectNo" : "5544A",
    "dataDate" : "2015-02-13T08:00:00.000Z"
}, {
    "amount" : 130060,
    "projectNo" : "5544A",
    "dataDate" : "2015-02-20T08:00:00.000Z"
}]
```

What I need to do now is limit the returned data to just the last date of the month:

```
[{
    "amount" : 137947,
    "projectNo" : "5544A",
    "dataDate" : "2015-01-30T08:00:00.000Z"
}, {
    "amount" : 130060,
    "projectNo" : "5544A",
    "dataDate" : "2015-02-27T08:00:00.000Z"
}]
```

edit: Sample document from the collection:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5527e724fc53ec16bc5fe57a"),
  "projectNo" : "5544G",
  "cpfoNo" : "1448R",
  "cpfoDate" : ISODate("2014-10-20T07:00:00Z"),
  "description" : "INC 6 CO 176 - Booster Pump",
  "pcoNo" : "1510",
  "approvedAmount" : null,
  "days" : null,
  "remarks" : null,
  "itemNo" : "0005",
  "costCode" : "5030.09900.0000.0000",
  "itemTitle" : "Painting - Hasson",
  "bdgtEst" : 0.0,
  "bdgtProp" : 745.0,
  "bdgtAprv" : 745.0,
  "bdgtAppd" : 745.0,
  "dataDate" : ISODate("2014-12-12T08:00:00Z")
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your document?

Comment: @Michael Have you had a chance to look at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @chidrian for getting me started. This is the solution that works for me.  Probably an extra step with projecting month and year keys, but it works.

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "projectNo": "$projectNo",
            "dataDate": "$dataDate"
        },
        "sum": "$bdgtAppd"
    }
}
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "projectNo": "$_id.projectNo",
        "dataDate": "$_id.dataDate",
        "amount": 1
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "projectNo": "$projectNo",
        "amount": 1,
        "dataDate": 1,
        "month": {
            $month: "$dataDate"
        },
        "year": {
            "$year": "$dataDate"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$sort": {
        projectNo: 1,
        dataDate: 1
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "projectNo": "$projectNo",
            "month": "$month",
            "year": "$year"
        },
        "dataDate": {
            "$last": "$dataDate"
        },
        "amount": {
            "$last": "$amount"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$sort": {
        projectNo: 1,
        dataDate: 1
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "projectNo": "$_id.projectNo",
        "dataDate": 1,
        "amount": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for an initial **`$project`** pipeline stage, simply start with a **`$group`** step and the following pipeline stages will yield the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "projectNo": "$projectNo", 
                "dataDate": "$dataDate"
            },
            "amount": {"$sum": "$bdgtAppd"}            
        }       
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,            
            "projectNo": "$_id.projectNo",
            "dataDate": "$_id.dataDate",
            "amount": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$projectNo",                        
            "dataDate": {"$first" : "$dataDate"},  
            "amount": {"$first" : "$amount"}         
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,            
            "projectNo": "$_id",
            "dataDate": 1,
            "amount": 1
        }
    }
]);
```

With the following sample documents (included the relevant fields only as the minimum test case):

```
db.collection.insert([
    /* 0 */
    {
        "projectNo" : "5544A",
        "bdgtAppd" : 3,
        "dataDate" : ISODate("2015-01-02T08:00:00.000Z")
    },

    /* 1 */
    {
        "projectNo" : "5544A",
        "bdgtAppd" : 7,
        "dataDate" : ISODate("2015-01-28T08:00:00.000Z")
    },

    /* 2 */
    {
        "projectNo" : "5544A",
        "bdgtAppd" : 5,
        "dataDate" : ISODate("2015-01-28T08:00:00.000Z")
    },

    /* 3 */
    {
        "projectNo" : "5544B",
        "bdgtAppd" : 15,
        "dataDate" : ISODate("2015-02-13T08:00:00.000Z")
    },

    /* 4 */
    {
        "projectNo" : "5544G",
        "bdgtAppd" : 10,
        "dataDate" : ISODate("2015-02-27T08:00:00.000Z")
    },

    /* 5 */
    {
        "projectNo" : "5544G",
        "bdgtAppd" : 25,
        "dataDate" : ISODate("2015-02-27T08:00:00.000Z")
    },
]);
```

the above aggregation produces:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "dataDate" : ISODate("2015-01-28T08:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 12,
            "projectNo" : "5544A"
        }, 
        {
            "dataDate" : ISODate("2015-02-13T08:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 15,
            "projectNo" : "5544B"
        }, 
        {
            "dataDate" : ISODate("2015-02-27T08:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 35,
            "projectNo" : "5544G"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I figured limiting the keys to only the ones I care about would speed things up a bit but I forgot that $group does the same thing.

This aggregation gets me really close, there are a few cases where it is correct and others where it picks the first dataDate of the month. I feel like there's a way to do this in one pass but I'm worried that I have to get the dates first, then pass the dates to a $match.

Comment: @Splitty No worries. I tried with a few test documents and couldn't come up with a lesser pipeline stages query, that was as far as I could get with the requirements you provided. The highlight is how you are doing your initial grouping; in the above you want to group on the project date.

Comment: If possible, can you provide the minimum test case (sample documents and expected result from that sample collection), perhaps we could find another approach?

Comment: Actually you were on to something with this, I added more sort operators between the groups and I'm getting closer to what I need. Is there a mongodb fiddle? I noticed there is now sqlfiddle dot com

Comment: @Splitty Let me know when you hit the jackpot :-)